# CSS animation not working on chrome even by adding -webkit prefixe

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm trying to rotate a [mat-icon](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview)

in css I'm using the webkit prefix. For information this code is working on FF.

```
@keyframes rotateIcon {
  0% {
    rotate: 0deg;
  }
  100% {
    rotate: 360deg;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateIcon {
  0% {
    rotate: 0deg;
  }
  100% {
    rotate: 360deg;
  }
}

.animatedIcon {
  animation: rotateIcon 2s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: rotateIcon 2s infinite;

}
```

In HTML

```
<mat-icon class="status-icon animatedIcon">
  {{getStatusIcon('IN_PROGRESS')}}
</mat-icon>
```

I'm getting static icon that does not rotate.

Here's a [snippet](https://angular-gsmyxp.stackblitz.io/)

I'm working on this version of chrome :86.0.4240.75

Comment: Could you put up a working snippet - just in case it's got something to do with the way the icon is being included.

Comment: Yes, I added a snippet that works on FF, but I can't open the link in chrome ( may be a browser problem ) you should be able to open it in chrome unless it's a stackblitz problem

Comment: Your snippet does not work for me in Edge, Chrome or FF - I suspect there are some dependencies in there that are OK on your system (FF) but not for me. Please put up enough code as a Stackoverflow snippet, not on some outside service, that shows the problem. I guess you realise there was a typo (I think) in the class name used in the HTML, but suspect that isn't your problem if it worked on FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
@keyframes rotateIcon {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateIcon {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.animatedIcon {
  animation: rotateIcon 2s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: rotateIcon 2s infinite;

}
```

and for HTML, do this:

```
<mat-icon class="status-icon animatedIcon">
  {{getStatusIcon('IN_PROGRESS')}}
</mat-icon>
```

**Solution Details:**

You have used the wrong CSS property. The property name is `transform` and it takes a function `rotate(0deg)`.

Comment: Yes ! the problem was the `rotate`--> `transform` ! thanks ! you can update your answer because I made a mistake when I added the code example by writing animatedIcon instread of rotateIcon.

Comment: Just a small note here: **prefixed styles should go before the unprefixed** styles. In that case, the browser will use a prefixed version only when an unprefixed version is not supported.